# Eigenvalue problem with Robin boundary conditions at both ends

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

From Walter A. Strauss's *Partial Differential Equations*:

> Consider the eigenvalue problem with Robin boundary conditions at both ends:
> $$ -X'' = \lambda X, \qquad X'(0) - a_0 X(0) = 0, \qquad X'(l) - a_1 X(l)=0 $$ **a)** Show that $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $a_0+a_1=-a_0a_1 l$  
>  **b)** Find the eigenfunctions corresponding to the zero eigenvalue 
>   **Hint:** First solve ODE for $X(x)$. The solutions are not sines or cosines.

---

I was able to do part a) if $\lambda=0$ then $a_0+a_1=-a_0a_1 l$. But the rest of part a) and part b) I am unable to do. Can someone please help me to finish this problem?

Comment: Haven't though through:  What happens if you work with $Y(x) = X(x) - \left((x/l)a_0X(0) + ((l-x)/l)a_1 X(l)\right)$?

Comment: @EricTowers : When $\lambda=0$ the solution is $X(x)=Ax+B$. Plugging boundary conditions I get two equations as $A-a_0B=0$ and $A+a_1(Al+B)=0$.  Then in order to find the **eigen function ** do I have to solve one of  $A-a_0B=0$ or $A+a_1(Al+B)=0$.  When I use $A-a_0B=0$ I get $A=a_0B$. Then how can I find B and how does it become a function of x

Comment: @EricTowers : Also I don't understand what you have given as $Y(x) = X(x) - \left((x/l)a_0X(0) + ((l-x)/l)a_1 X(l)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue, then $X(x)$ will be of the form $X(x) = mx + c$.  Plug this into the boundary conditions, solve for $m$ and $c$, and voilà!  The converse for part (a) is just as easy - if the condition is satisfied, then show there exist $m$ and $c$ so that $X(x)$ satisfies the boundary conditions.